# Reading in excel file into pandas depending of the month

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement, filepath

I'm trying to read in an Excel file into Pandas.

I am using the following code to get the previous month:

```
today = datetime.date.today() 
first = today.replace(day=1) 
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Then I go to pull in the file without any errors:

```
if lastMonth == 12 : pods = pd.ExcelFile(r'\\somedrive\PODS data - PODS data - Jan 19.xlsx')
elif lastMonth == 1 : pods = pd.ExcelFile(r'\\somedrive\PODS data - Feb 19.xlsx')
else lastMonth == 2 : pods = pd.ExcelFile(r'\\somedrive\PODS data - Mar 19.xlsx')
```

I then attempt to see if it was successfully pulled in by typing `pods` and I get the following error:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 pods
>
> NameError: name 'pods' is not defined
>
> I'm sure it is something simple, but I can't quite figure out what it
>   is

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is in yout Excel file?

Comment: It is just general headcount file that contains employee name, id and dept

Answer (score 2):

As per your question, lastMonth is in date format and if you define that with any number then it might give you error.

I have tried below code that you can try:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today() 
first = today.replace(day=1) 
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
lastMonth.month

if lastMonth.month == 12:
    pods = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\path\Python\File1.xlsx')
elif lastMonth.month == 1 :
    pods = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\path\Python\File2.xlsx')
else :
    pods = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\path\Python\File3.xlsx')
```

for the last statement(else statement), you do not need to define the condition. let me know if its work for you.